# #NAME in Access report expression

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 report which has a table as a data source. I have a few columns of data that directly pull data from the table in a summarized way (using report groups) and the last column is the total of the first 6 columns. Simple enough.

Now the expression that calculates the sum of those 6 columns sometimes returns `#NAME?` and sometimes does not. I have more than triple-checked for any error, typo, whatever.

1. There is no space in front of my expression;
2. The expression does start with an `=`;
3. The references to columns in the table are all valid;
4. No control has a name even remotely similar to any column in the source table;
5. I have tried generating the expression using the expression builder;
6. There is no conditional formatting tied to any control;
7. There is no VBA code used at all in generating the report.

Also, sometimes if I copy the one of the boxes with `#NAME?`, delete it and paste it back then *all* the `#NAME?` errors disappear. Then I save and reopen the report and the errors are back.

I'm out of ideas for this. I can't post screenshots or distribute the file due to its nature.

Thanks !

Comment: You might try using VBA code instead to put values in your textbox using the reports Format event. This might lead you to the source of the problem.

Comment: I converted the Access file back to Access 2003 format (the user only has 2003 on her desktop...) and I haven't had this problem yet since conversion... I honestly don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems...The solution was that I have used unicode characters in Names. For example a Text Box with the control source "dataščž" had the Name "datačšž". This was working in previous versions of Access, but not anymore. Changing the Name "datacsz" solved the problem.